# How to search for a certain keyword using SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I recently implemented SpeechRecognition into a personal assistant that I am creating, but I am facing an issue. Whenever I am playing music through my speakers, it continues to listen for me talking, and although it hears me, it does not stop because the sound through the speakers keeps it activated.

I imagine that this could be fixed in a similar way to Amazon Alexa, Google Home, Siri, etc by muting the audio when a certain keyword is spoken. The issue with this is, to my knowledge, SpeechRecognition cannot do this.

```
def takeCommand():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio=r.listen(source)
        try:
            statement=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
            print(f"user said: {statement}\n")

        except Exception as e:
            return "None"
        return statement
```

Given this code ^, I can only process the words once the clause has been completed. I could possibly try and implement a second script that searches for this keyword, but my python skills are rather elementary and I'd rather see if I could get it all working concisely. Let me know if you know how I could do this!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually try the following:

First...setting a duration for how long your Personal Assistant would listen...to do that..just replace..

```
audio=r.listen(source)
```

to

```
audio=r.record(source, duration=4)
```

You can change the duration value.

Second...to ignore background noise to some extent..and to that...just add the following  line

```
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
```

before

```
audio=r.record(source, duration=4)
```

Let me know if it works :)